# How to get wp7 pre-compiling symbol that indicates if program is either launched on emulator or device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there a way to know on what platform my application is compiled?
e.g. windows phone device / windows phone emulator?

Is there any way to retrieve target pro-processing symbols and check it later on like this :

```
#if PHONE_DEVICE
....
#elif
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense - an application isn't *compiled* on a real phone or an emulator; it's *running* on a real phone or an emulator.

In other words, this can't be a compile-time constant - it has to be an execution-time property.

You can find out what environment an application is running in using the [`Environment.DeviceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.environment.devicetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property, which returns one of the [`DeviceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.devicetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) enum values: `Device` or `Emulator`.

Comment: Jon Skeet: you're right, i didn't write my question properly, but in the IDE you're able to change the environment (emulator/device) there must be some flags become true when this happen

Comment: @igalk: That's just changing how the code is launched - not how the code is built.

Comment: Why not just `#if DEBUG`, as if you are on an emulator *you're most likely debugging*.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can determine at compile time.
Your code either *runs*  in an emulator or on a device and you should therefore do something like:

```
if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == Microsoft.Devices.DeviceType.Emulator)
{
  // Do something when running in an emulator
}
else
{
  // Do something else when running on a device
}
```